# Rails 6 ActionText Error undefined method `body' for "":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actiontext

I get the following error when I try viewing the posts form on the browser on Rails 6. I have a admin/posts_controller.rb. The posts have a title and a body and I would like to add actiontext using trix editor on the body

```
NoMethodError at /admin/posts/new
undefined method `body' for "":String

Hint: `body` is being called on a `String` object, which might not be the type of object you were expecting.
```

`app/models/post.rb`

```
has_rich_text :body
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
mount_uploader :banner, BannerUploader
```

`admin/posts/_form.html.erb`

```
<div class="form-group">
   <%= form.label :body %>
   <%= form.rich_text_area :body, id: :post_body, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>
```

I am rendering using the layout `admin.html.erb`  instead of `application.html.erb`

Here are my relevant files

`app/packs/admin.js`

```
require("trix")
require("@rails/actiontext")
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"
// import the bootstrap javascript module
import "jquery"
import "bootstrap"
import "feather"
import "perfect-scrollbar"
require('./dash/dash')
import "js-cookie"
require("@nathanvda/cocoon")
// Load Datatables
import dt from "datatables.net";
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
    dt(window, $);
});
const dataTables = [];
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
  if (dataTables.length === 0 && $('.data-table').length !== 0) {
    $('.data-table').each((_, element) => {
      dataTables.push($(element).DataTable({
        pageLength: 50
      }));
    });
  }
});
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:before-cache", () => {
  while (dataTables.length !== 0) {
    dataTables.pop().destroy();
  }
});
// Import admin.css files
import '../stylesheets/admin'
require.context('../images/dash', true)
Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()
```

`app/javascripts/stylesheets/admin.scss`

```
@import "actiontext.scss";
@import "dashforge/fontawesome-all.scss";
@import "dashforge/ionicons.scss";
@import "dashforge/dashforge.scss"
```

`app/javascripts/actiontext.scss`

```
//
// Provides a drop-in pointer for the default Trix stylesheet that will format the toolbar and
// the trix-editor content (whether displayed or under editing). Feel free to incorporate this
// inclusion directly in any other asset bundle and remove this file.
//
//= require trix/dist/trix
// We need to override trix.css's image gallery styles to accommodate the
// <action-text-attachment> element we wrap around attachments. Otherwise,
// images in galleries will be squished by the max-width: 33%; rule.
.trix-content {
  .attachment-gallery {
    > action-text-attachment,
    > .attachment {
      flex: 1 0 33%;
      padding: 0 0.5em;
      max-width: 33%;
    }
    &.attachment-gallery--2,
    &.attachment-gallery--4 {
      > action-text-attachment,
      > .attachment {
        flex-basis: 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
      }
    }
  }
  action-text-attachment {
    .attachment {
      padding: 0 !important;
      max-width: 100% !important;
    }
  }
}
```

`config/application.rb`

```
require "action_text/engine"
```

I am really at my limit here. I am not aware of what I may be missing. Let me know if I require to provide any further details

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who comes across this. I have realized the cause of this issue

When using ActionText you should not add a corresponding column to your table.

i.e. You should not have a `body` column on your `posts table` if you want to add actiontext on `body`.

Simply call `has_rich_text :body` in your model and make sure you have no `body` column on your `posts` table

So in this instance, the solution was to remove my body column with the following migration and that was it

`Remove Body Column from Posts Migration`

```
remove_column :posts, :body
```

Comment: thank you, i was breaking my head about this.